# Assembly Newlines

Tags: string, assembly, x86

I've written a simple bootloader in Assembly (NASM syntax), however when I run it in QEMU, the newlines show up like this:

[image]

This is my code:

Is there a way to stop `0Ah` from pushing the lines forward?

```
.loop_top:

mov si, text_string ; Put string position into SI
call print_string   ; Call our string-printing routine

loop .loop_top

jmp $           ; Jump here - infinite loop!


text_string db "This is my cool new OS!", 0Ah, 0
```

Comment: You should show your `print_string` so others can have an idea where the problem is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, obviously :-) your "print_string" subroutine takes the 0x0a seriously -- it's called "LF", and it does just that, advances to the next line.

My guess is that using 0x0a 0x0d will do the trick.

Comment: +1.  It might be a bit more "normal" to switch the order - at least then it will match the common windows line endings.  You might also be able to find a setting for your terminal program that will make it behave differently.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that sending a `\r` will make the cursor return to the left side of the screen. So, you should use `\r\n` or something similar to make new lines.

I'm not sure without more details. I'm not for sure how your print_string procedure is implemented. If implemented by BIOS calls, such as by cycling through the string using int 0x10, AH=0x0E, then the above solution will work, or you can do something like using int 0x10, AH=0x03 to adjust the cursor position manually.